# How does a linked dataflow block cancel the target block

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

In TPL Dataflow, when a block is linked to another block with propagation, it will forward exceptions and also cancellations. I can imagine that forwarding an exception is simply done by using `dataFlowBlock.Fault(exception)`, but I'm curious as to how the cancellation is forwarded as there is no such thing as `dataFlowBlock.Cancel()`. Is it done through the same `Fault()` method using the by passing `TaskCancelledException` as an argument?

**Update:**

To clarify, consider the following example where only block1 is created with a `CancelationToken` via options, and block2 isn't. Block1 is linked to block2 with propagation:

```
block1 { CancellationToken = ct } -> block2 { }
```

When ct receives a cancelation request, block1 completion transitions to canceled. My question is what happens to block2 at this point? Does block1 actively cancel block2, and if so, does it do it using `block.Fault(TaskCanceledException)`? Or does it use some internal ocus-pocus that magically cancels block2 even though it was created without cancelation token?

Comment: You can actually [check the code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/SourceCore.cs#L128). When a source completes the library itself [calls Fault or Complete](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/Common.cs#L550) on the linked targets. That's an implementation detail though

Comment: BTW why ask about cancellation in the first place? Blocks *shouldn't* raise exceptions unless they've failed completely and the pipeline has to be torn down. They are meant to handle a stream of messages. Some will always fail and those could be wrapped and redirected eg to a logging component, using LinkTo with a predicate. They don't have to bring down the entire pipeline

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would like to understand how cancelation is propagated when linking with propagation so I know what is the expected behavior (and more importantly what isn't, meaning there's a problem somewhere in the pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think we're on the same page with the updated post. In short cancellation is not flowed onto linked blocks if propagation is not true.

```
[TestFixture]
public class DataFlowTests
{

    [Test]
    public async Task DataflowTest()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 200, CancellationToken = cts.Token });
        var action = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Task.Delay(100), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 5 });
        buffer.LinkTo(action, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = false});

        foreach (var data in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
        {
            if (data > 10) break;
            await buffer.SendAsync(data);
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        //action.Complete();
        await action.Completion;
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.Completion.Status);
        Console.WriteLine(action.Completion.Status);
    }
}
```

That sample will hang forever waiting for `action` to complete. Now calling `Complete()` explicilty on the `ActionBlock<>` yields these resultant stauses:

```
Cancelled - buffer
RanToCompletion - action
```

Finally propagating completion yields the same result without having to manually call completion on downstream blocks:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DataFlowTests
{

    [Test]
    public async Task DataflowTest()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 200, CancellationToken = cts.Token });
        var action = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Task.Delay(100), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 5 });
        buffer.LinkTo(action, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true});

        foreach (var data in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
        {
            if (data > 10) break;
            await buffer.SendAsync(data);
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        await action.Completion;
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.Completion.Status);
        Console.WriteLine(action.Completion.Status);
    }
}
```

Yields statuses:

```
Canceled - buffer
RanToCompletion - action
```

Note that a cancellation does **not** cause the entire pipeline to become cancelled. Other blocks simply complete. Now if an exception other than a cancelled notification comes through then the pipeline will be faulted through `...Fault(..)`. Otherwise its juts standard completion propagation.

Comment: Thanks, we are, I have one last bonus question, do you know what happens to a canceled block's still running tasks (i.e. degrees of parallelism > 1)? Are they tentatively ran to completion or are they forcefully terminated so to speak?

Comment: When cancelled a block will finish processing but not accept any new messages not already buffered.

Answer (score 2):

Cancellation comes in the form of an option, `CancellationToken`, on  [`ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) The token passed will complete the blocks successfully. What that means is the blocks will treat an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) differently than other exceptions thrown in the pipeline and cause the blocks to simply complete once done processing. Cancellation is intended to work by sharing a single CTS and using the associated tokens into the block options. Then when the CTS is cancelled all blocks get the cancellation signal.

Also more can be found [here from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-dataflow-block).

Pointing to your actual question in the comments, this might explain  things a little more.

> When a dataflow block is canceled explicitly, the AggregateException object contains OperationCanceledException in the InnerExceptions property

Also:

> The TPL provides a mechanism that enables tasks to coordinate cancellation in a cooperative manner. To enable dataflow blocks to participate in this cancellation mechanism, set the CancellationToken property. When this CancellationToken object is set to the canceled state, all dataflow blocks that monitor this token finish execution of their current item but do not start processing subsequent items. These dataflow blocks also clear any buffered messages, release connections to any source and target blocks, and transition to the canceled state. By transitioning to the canceled state, the Completion property has the Status property set to Canceled, unless an exception occurred during processing. In that case, Status is set to Faulted.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

This is a lot quoted text but the source link is provided and the explanations are well written.

So the blocks don't actively propagate cancellation. However, once the cancelled block finishes, with propagate to true, will flow that completion task right along with a cancelled or faulted state.

Comment: Thanks @JSteward, but perhaps my question wasn't clear, I understand how to create a "cancellable" block using the the options, my question is: regardless of the options used during block creation, when linking blocks with propagation, the source block somehow "gains" the ability to cancel the target block upon cancellation. I was wondering if this was done by faulting the target block with a `TaskCancelledException` or through some other mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you elaborate on this:` _gains the ability to cancel the target block_ what exactly are you referring to, was this meant **gains the ability to _Complete_ the target block**

Comment: @JSteward Dataflow cancellation isn't related to CancellationToken or Task cancellation. Dataflow is a higher level library that handles linking and propagating completion from one source to one or more targets internally

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not really following you. I can agree with the second sentence: _high level library..._. However, I don't see how `CancellationTokens` and `Task` cancellation don't apply. After all you pass a cancellation token into the block and/or pipeline for the express purpose of canceling the block/pipeline. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @JSteward I think the confusion here is coming from the fact that we're all mixing active block cancelation with passive cancelation propagation. I'm going to update the question with a concrete example to specify exactly what piece of the puzzle I'm after, hopefully it'll clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

The source code that runs whenever a block propagates its completion to a linked block can be found [here](https://source.dot.net/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Internal/Common.cs.html#43ef227d2325fbe9) or [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/67d74fca70d4670ad503e23dba9d6bc8a1b5909e/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/Common.cs#L541). Below is a simplified version of this code:

```
internal static void PropagateCompletion(Task sourceCompletionTask, IDataflowBlock target)
{
    AggregateException exception =
        sourceCompletionTask.IsFaulted ? sourceCompletionTask.Exception : null;

    if (exception != null) target.Fault(exception); else target.Complete();
}
```

There is no provision for propagating cancellation. If the block completed in a faulted state, the exception is propagated to the linked block. In any other case the linked block is just marked for completion.

AFAIK the one and only case that a block transitions to a canceled state is when the `CancellationToken` that was supplied at its creation becomes canceled. For example if you try to `throw new OperationCanceledException()` from inside its lambda function, nothing happens and the processed message is just ignored.